# in Postgres, use array of values for INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql

have an array of values. I wish to INSERT each of them as records if it does not already exist. can this be done *in one statement* in SQL?

traditional javascript approach:

```
[4,5,8]forEach( x => queryParams(
   insert into t1( c1 ) values( $1 )
   where not exists( select 1 from t1 where c1 = $1`,
   [x]
);
```

what would be ideal is something like

```
queryParams(
 `some fancy SQL here`,
 [ `{${join[4,5,8]}}` ]
);
```

many reasons for this, including limiting the cost of server round trips and transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query to find the values that don't exist matching a condition:

```
INSERT INTO Records (X)
    SELECT X
    FROM unnest(ARRAY[4,5,8]) T (X)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Records WHERE X = T.X);
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e0334/29/0

Edited above to use `unnest`

Comment: that works, but not very elegant, esp if the array is very long. would be nice to have one SQL statement where the array is an argument, rather than creating the statement anew with each array.

Comment: You can also unnest an array like updated answer above.